# RiaServices DomainService Server side exception problem

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wcf, wcf-ria-services

Currently i'm working on a Silverlight project that depend on RIA with LinqToSQL 
And I’m using .NET version 4

Sometimes when we add a few records from the client side that contain some missing some data like null or wrong reference the server raise an exception and throw it to the client
By throwing  DomainOperationException along with error details that explain the REFRENCE name, And that’s great.

So I can handle it on the client and popup the appropriate message to the user
And that is working good on the development computer.

But when I deployed the project on  the remote server , I found that the server is not sending the Detailed Error message along with DomainOperationException.

I read so many threads about this issue and they said it’s for security reasons .
And they said if you want the exception to hold the detailed error message you should add the following to your Web.Config

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageEnabled="True" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

But it’s seems only work with WCF services  and it’s not working with domainServices.

I mean it’s work for only  tag and not work for  tag

So I tried another solution , and that is to override the OnError method on the DomainService in the server side.

And this solution worked on the development computer, but on the remote server is not triggered at all.

Did anybody faced a similar problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by adding

`<customErrors mode="Off" />`

To the web.config